# sklearn svm normalize poly kernel

Tags: scikit-learn, kernel, svm, weka

I'm now doing a text classification project. At first, I used Weka, its SVM method has a normalized polynomial kernel, and I got the best result using that kernel. I'm trying to do the same task using sklearn. I found that the svm.SVC only has 'poly' kernel. So is that possible to do the normalized polynomial kernel using sklearn?

```
random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='poly', gamma='auto', C = 2.0,decision_function_shape='ova',probability=False,random_state = random_state) 
cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=10, test_size=0.25, random_state=random_state)
score = cross_val_score(clf, X_scaled, k, cv=cv)
scores2 = cross_val_score(clf, X_scaled, k, cv = cv,scoring='f1_macro')
```

Comment: You could achieve good results using GridSearch to tune the parameters of the SVM in sklearn. Post your code and I could provide an example

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've updated the core code. I know that doing a GridSearch may improve the performance, but I guess it may not make up the gap between different kernels.

Comment: Yes that's true. Using gridsearch the results are still not good ?